# json Ajax request returns every html element of the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, perl, mason

```
<script language="JavaScript">  
 var result = {};  
 var data;  
 function load_metadata (id) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/video/metadata",
    type: "POST",
    data: id,
    cache: false,
    //dataType: "json",
    //contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        result = data;  
    },
    error: function(e, xhr){ 
        alert('slideshow data load error: ');
    }
});         
 alert(result.toSource());  //({})
}   
</script>
```

**/video/metadata** (mason component)

```
<%class>   
use JSON;   
has 'data';      
</%class>   
<%init>

use Data::Dumper;
print STDERR  Dumper($.data); # $VAR1 = '"815"'

my $item_hash->{'item'} = "test";   # Valid JSON in JSONLint.com

my $json = to_json($item_hash, { ascii => 1 });

print  STDERR  Dumper($json); # $VAR1 = '{"item":"test"}';
</%init>
<% $json %>
```

It is returning every html element of the page and not the json from component call!
specifying a datatype/contentType give a parserserror

Comment: Just a note, this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: also has nothing to do with the AJAX.. one problem,you can't print anything other than a single JSON output

Answer (score 0):

just in case some one has same pb

forgot to add

`<%flags>

    extends => undef

</%flags>`

`inherit => undef` flag in order to shorcut the component inheritance,
uncommented the dataType and
added `'async': false,`

so the final working code is:

```
<script language="JavaScript">  
 var result = {};  

 function load_metadata (id) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/video/metadata",
    type: "POST",
    data: id,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    'async': false,
    success: function(data) {
        result = data;  
    },
    error: function(e, xhr){ 
        alert('slideshow data load error: ');
    }
});         
 alert(result.toSource());  //({"item":"test"})
}   
</script>
```

**/video/metadata** (mason component)

```
<%flags>   
    extends => undef   
</%flags>   

<%class>   
use JSON;   
has 'data';      
</%class>  

<%init>

use Data::Dumper;
print STDERR  Dumper($.data); # $VAR1 = '"815"'

my $item_hash->{'item'} = "test";   # Valid JSON in JSONLint.com

my $json = to_json($item_hash, { ascii => 1 });

print  STDERR  Dumper($json); # $VAR1 = '{"item":"test"}';
</%init>
<% $json %>
```

hope it saves you few hours